# Regarding the OS deployement using WDS service in Windows 2019

Tags: windows, operating-system, os-dependent

I have two machines Windows 2019 and Windows 10 in my Hyper-V. I had configured active directory in my server machine and connected the client machine to the domain. I had installed and configured the WDS service role and started the service. The next step of it is to start the client machine (Windows 10), as soon as it starts it will boot from the network path instead from CD. I had checked the order of the BIOS it is positioned correctly. However, the client machine is not restarting from the network, what might be the reason? Can any one share the troubleshooting steps that are involved in this?

Following are the steps that I made sure that they are proper:

1. The order in the boot order in BIOS is positioned properly, by keeping the "Legacy network adapter" in the first place.
2. Firewall has been turned off, the Windows 10 machine had been properly made as the part of the domain(member server).
3. IP address of the two machines belong to the same network.
4. DNS and DHCP had been properly configured and are in the range of network.
5. 67 and 66 scope options has been configured.

Expectations:
Please share any other troubleshooting steps are involved in this or not.